# A simple nginx config doesn't work

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, domain, static-routes

I'm trying to create a simple configuration for nginix for testing. I have 2 files:

```
/home/user1/tmp_server_data/main_page
/home/user1/tmp_server_data/.well-known/test1
```

And my config:

```
  # /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
server {
  root /home/user1/tmp_server_data;

  location ~ /.well-known {
    allow all;
  }
}
```

The domain is setup also to point to the ip address where the nginx is installed. But the domain doesn't get resolved, all

```
(www.)my_domain.com/main_page
(www.)my_domain.com/.well-known/test1
```

return nothing. Where's an issue?

Comment: You need to post more information - the whole Nginx configuration, server logs. You look like you're trying to set up SSL certificates - you may find my tutorial on this useful: https://www.photographerstechsupport.com/tutorials/hosting-wordpress-on-aws-tutorial-part-5-free-https-https2-for-wordpress-using-lets-encrypt-aws/

Comment: @Tim, everything else is untouched.

Comment: Yes, but "everything else" is important. You seem to be on a Debian-based system, and they infamously _do not_ use the nginx configuration shipped with nginx, but instead replace it with their own.

Comment: We don't know what the defaults are. You haven't posted error logs. If you read the tutorial I posted a link to you can probably figure this out yourself. You won't get any useful help if you don't give enough information for people to help you, instead your question will be closed.

Comment: @Tim, but I can open it again, right?

Comment: I believe you can ask another question if this one is closed. You just need to give more information if you want help.

Comment: You have to add  this.     server_name   my_domain.com;

Comment: @gloom700, tnx.